# How to make Excel-like data bars?

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts

I would like to make a grid where each cell background is partially filled according to the numerical value being represented (on a scale from 0 to 1).  Similar functionality to the one requested in [this TeX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/partially-coloring-cell-background-to-fake-histogram).

How can I achieve this with *Mathematica*?

Comment: It always helps if you give some example data and list some *Mathematica* code that you gave tried.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can also use the `HorizontalGauge` function introduced in version 9. For example:

```
bar = HorizontalGauge[#, {0, 100}, GaugeMarkers -> "ScaleRange", 
    GaugeStyle -> {Darker@Green, GrayLevel[0.95]}, TicksStyle -> None,
    GaugeFrameSize -> None, ScalePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
    LabelStyle -> None, Epilog -> Text[Style[#, FontSize -> 15], Scaled[{0.8, 0.5}]]] &;

Grid[Map[bar, RandomInteger[{10, 90}, {4, 4}], {2}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm embarrassed to be getting so many upvotes for my stolen version of your answer... :)

Answer (score 22):

I liked rm-rf's gauged solution so much that I made an interactive version:

```
bar[n_] := DynamicModule[{x = n}, 
HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[x], {0, 100}, GaugeMarkers -> "ScaleRange", 
 GaugeStyle -> {Darker@Green, GrayLevel[0.95]}, TicksStyle -> None, 
 GaugeFrameSize -> None, ScalePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 200, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/5, LabelStyle -> None, 
 Epilog -> 
  Text[Style[Dynamic[x], FontSize -> 15], Scaled[{0.8, 0.5}]]]]
Grid[Table[bar[RandomInteger[{10, 90}]], {4}, {4}], Frame -> All]
```

Ideal for those last minute adjustments to that troublesome dataset...

[image: animated]

Comment: "Ideal for those last minute adjustments to that troublesome dataset..." or to show on conference that global warming is a fact. :p

Comment: @kuba :) I'd laugh if I thought it never happened...

Comment: "All that pressure about results...". But let's not talk about this. I like this +1.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Something like this?

```
Grid[Map[Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.8], 
     Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{#, 1}]], Black, 
     Style[Text[#], Large]}, AspectRatio -> 0.2] &, 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 3}], {2}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Of course you can place the `Text` and style to taste. Here is a slightly more complex version:

```
Grid[Map[Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.8], 
     Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{#, 1}]], Black, 
     Inset[Text[
       Style[NumberForm[#, {3, 3}], Large, 
        FontFamily -> "Franklin Gothic"]], Scaled[{0.8, 0.5}]]}, 
    AspectRatio -> 0.2] &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 3}], {2}], 
 Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.9]], Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

It would be straightforward to create a function that took a matrix of numbers and generated this.